# Node.js frequent pod restarts in Kubernetes due to OOM

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, out-of-memory

i am facing OOM issue with Next.js on Kubernetes.

Pod memory keeps growing but it doesn't revert back to previous memory, it keeps growing linearly until it reaches a certain limit and Kubernetes restarts the pods.

Initially i thought it might be something to do with the code, garbage collector not being able to free up the memory but it doesn't look so, because i deployed another app, plain Next.js which renders just a random text and has minimal dependencies and behaves the same.

Now, i am Dockerizing my application, my apps are in a monorepo locally managed by turborepo, and the dockerized application i am hosting them/deploying in a Kubernetes cluster.

```js
ARG NODE=node:16.15.0-alpine

FROM ${NODE} as deps
RUN yarn set version 1.22.19

WORKDIR /app
COPY apps/plain-nextjs/ ./
RUN yarn install

FROM ${NODE} as builder
ENV NODE_ENV production 

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/ ./
RUN yarn build

FROM ${NODE} as production
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production 


RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3005

ENV PORT 3005

CMD node --max-old-space-size=360 server.js
```

The pod memory limit in K8 helm charts is defined as 512MB, so in Node.js/Next.js i assign 75% of that, based on recommendations online.

I am also using path based routing from Kubernetes, i use 1 domain/URL for several related mini-web-apps which are separated by routes, istio path based routing.

In next.config.js i defined the following:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack", "url-loader"],
    });
    return config;
  },
  reactStrictMode: false,
  output: "standalone",
  swcMinify: true,
  compress: true,
  basePath: "/plain-nextjs",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Say that we use a domain https://mydomain.internal.io, for this particular app we setup in istio virtual-service to actually be redirected when users browse:

```js
https://mydomain.internal.io/plain-nextjs
```

Point is, i thought initially the memory leak happens because of some circular imports, or some garbage collection issue.

I cannot make sense and point finger why this is happening. Anyone might have any idea?

In addition, this is the package.json

```json
{
  "name": "plain-nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3005",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3005",
    "test": "jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.5",
    "next": "13.1.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint": "8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.5",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

So i am posting the github repo of plain-nextjs app where apparently i am facing OOM issue:

https://github.com/erkand-imeri/plain-nextjs-k8

And a screenshot from my staging environment, grafana visualization/chart of the memory consumption, the staging load is not big but the pattern is visible, pod memory keeps increasing and doesn't resort to its initial state.

[image]

Comment: Any update on this? The only thing which helped me was --max_space garbage collector setup. Since i've setup like 3/4 of memory, it doesnt crash (no memory overflow, it has enough time to take out garbage), but at the limits it starts to thorttle alot (alot!) and also static garbage collector size is not the best for scalable app.

Comment: We are having the same issue. With Next/Docker/Kubernetes setup pods get restarted frequently. Waiting for updates on issue.

Comment: Hey, are you guys using istio service mesh? Usually each app pod will be followed by additional pod for istio service mesh. This additional pod depending on your K8 configuration will take space, in my case it was taking additional 150MB, you can deduce this by tweaking istio sidecar settings in helm configuration, by limiting the service mesh with the necessary access to services. If you have full access to K8 configurations in your team, otherwise ask the adequate team to tweak.

Comment: Also, to continue the above, if you have service mesh enabled in k8, then K8 will create an additional pod for each app pod.

I put the K8 pod memory limit to 512MB in helm configs, istio service mesh pod was taking 150MB, usually without the service mesh pod in account you give 75% of memory in Node.js from the available in K8 pod (in my case it was 512MB per pod). Accounting the additional 150MB i played around with the configs

Comment: CMD node --max-old-space-size=200 --optimize_for_size --gc_interval=100 server.js

And this worked for me. The service/app was stabilized.

Comment: My assumption in my case is that i was facing lazy garbage collection which was leading to frequent pod restarts and OOM issues.